# How to create a symlink after I rooted my Samsung galaxy w GT-i8150?

Tags: file-system

How do I create a symlink from my `/sdcard/NaviSEA` to point to `/sdcard/external_sd/SD/NaviSEA`?

Even after rooting my device I still get "Operation not permitted" error and I did allow with `su` in my script :

```
$ su
# ln -s /sdcard/external_sd/SD/NaviSEA /sdcard/NaviSEA
```

Why doesn't my script work?

Answer (score 3):

Your external SD card is presumably (in pretty much every case) formatted as a FAT32 filesystem. [FAT32 does not support symbolic links](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=54600). Linking from a ext2/3/4 filesystem to a FAT32 filesystem would work, IIRC, but linking from FAT32 isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `/sdcard` is FUSE fs "link" for `/data/media`.

**Try this:**

```
ln -s /data/media/external_sd/SD/NaviSEA /data/media/NaviSEA
```

(I don't know what "external_sd" means on your device, but if this an external SD card you still can get errors.)